# Anaconda - installation error - The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows, anaconda, failed-installation

Getting and error as shown in the attached image. Unable to proceed ahead with the installation.

When I try to explicitly run the command which at which the installation is halted through Windows Command Prompt i get the same error.

**Command -** 
"C:\Users\Sharu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pythonw.exe" -E -s "C:\Users\Sharu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib_nsis.py" post_install

Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated ! Thanks in Advance ! Image is attached below -

[< Installtion-error-capture-click-me >](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaP6J.png)